# How to send mail after api endpoint is invoked, Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

My application is using React for frontend and Django & Django RestFramework. I am trying to send email. It is not possible from React Side. So what I thought is to create a Model Mail here in django with

```
class Mail(models.Model):
    MAIL_SENT= (
        ('Y', 'Yes'),
        ('N', 'No'),
    )
    send_to= models.CharField(max_length=120)
    reply_to= models.CharField(max_length=120)
    message= models.TextField()
    subject= models.TextField()
    mail_sent= models.CharField(max_length=1, default="Y", choices=MAIL_SENT)

    def __self__(self):
        return self.send_to
```

What I want to do is create an API endpoint for Mail and send method at the time of post method.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: yes you can, send the mail from the views function indjango whenever that end point is requested.

Comment: Please share your viewset code. You can override create/perform_create method to send email (it should be send using threading).

Answer (score 0):

Django provide send_mail function like this：

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

the docs link:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/

Answer (score 0):

You can use django `send_mail` function

example:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

you must use your `mail_port`, default `from_email` and `password`.

reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/

================================

so you can create your endpoint same like this

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class MailSender(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        to_email = request.data.get("to_email")
        send_mail(
            'Subject here',
            'Here is the message.',
            'from@example.com',
            ['to_email'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
        return Response({"message": "e-mail has been sent successfully"}, 
                        status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

you can also send mail using `threading` and then return the response.